# Binary File print key search c

Tags: c, file

Im trying to create a program that opens a binary file with a list of all the elements with their Atomic Number, Name and Symbol, in that order. The task for the program to be able to accept a name of element (should not be case sensitive) and print its atomic number and symbol

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    #include "elements.h"

#define NUM_ELEMENTS (118)

struct elementTag {
   int AtomicNumber;
   char Name[31];
   char Symbol[4];  // note: the longest Symbol has 3 characters
};

typedef struct elementTag ElementType;
    int
    main()
    {
        struct elementTag elements[NUM_ELEMENTS];

    int ctr;
    char ele[31];

    FILE *fbin;

    fbin = fopen ("ELEMENTS.bin", "rb");

    for ( ctr = 0; ctr < NUM_ELEMENTS; ctr ++)
    {
        fread (&elements[ctr], sizeof(struct elementTag), 1, fbin);
    }

    printf("\nInput element name to search: ");
    scanf("%s", ele);

    for ( ctr = 0; ctr < NUM_ELEMENTS; ctr ++)
    {
        if (strcmp(ele, elements[ctr].Name))
        {
            printf("Atomic Number: %d, Symbol: %s\n\n", elements[ctr].AtomicNumber, elements[ctr].Symbol);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NOT FOUND!\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose (fbin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Who creates the `ELEMENTS.bin` file? What is `elements.h` ? You need to check if `fopen` fails. There is a fundamental flaw inside your `for` loop, you should be able to find out yourself, it's obvious.

Comment: `strcmp` does not return a boolean, it returns a signed integer: negative, 0 or positive. Do not use it as a boolean, always check the value against an integer (usually 0, be it `>0`, `<0`, `==0` or `!=0`).

Comment: you will always say the input element is the first of the file you read except if the input is that first element, more some other remarks, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that code is suspicious :

> ```
> for ( ctr = 0; ctr < NUM_ELEMENTS; ctr ++)
> {
>     fread (&elements[ctr], sizeof(struct elementTag), 1, fbin);
> }
> ```

Above in the code you do not check if *fopen* returns NULL or not, and here you do not check the result of *fread*, so you suppose there is at least `NUM_ELEMENTS` records in the file.

But mainly you suppose the contents of the file correspond to a sequence of how *elementTag* are in memory, so the file is dedicated to a given compiler with associated compiling options on a given architecture, are you sure of that ?

Your way to read is false if your file contains their external representation like

```
1 Hydrogen H
2 Helium He
...
```

---

> ```
> char ele[31];
> ...
> scanf("%s", ele);
> ```

you do not have a protection against a too long input, and you do not check the EOF case

You can do

```
if (scanf("%30s", ele) == 1) {
  for (...
```

---

> The task for the program to be able to accept a name of element (should not be case sensitive)

your code uses

> ```
> if (strcmp(ele, elements[ctr].Name))
> ```

*strcmp* is case sensitive and you use wrong its result, use *strcasecmp*

---

In

> ```
> for ( ctr = 0; ctr < NUM_ELEMENTS; ctr ++)
> {
>     if (strcmp(ele, elements[ctr].Name))
>     {
>         printf("Atomic Number: %d, Symbol: %s\n\n", elements[ctr].AtomicNumber, elements[ctr].Symbol);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         printf("NOT FOUND!\n\n");
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

because of the wrong use of *strcmp* you will always says you find the first element except if the input element is the first element. Using correctly the result of *strcmp* you will always say `NOT FOUND` except if the input is the first element, and stop to look at the other possibilities.

The error case must be out of the loop or knowing the end of the loop is reach, for instance :

```
 for ( ctr = 0; ; ctr ++)
 {
     if (ctr == NUM_ELEMENTS)
     {
         printf("NOT FOUND!\n\n");
         break;
     }

     if (!strcasecmp(ele, elements[ctr].Name))
     {
         printf("Atomic Number: %d, Symbol: %s\n\n", elements[ctr].AtomicNumber, elements[ctr].Symbol);
          break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: The filename is `ELEMENTS.bin`, which suggests that the file format could be correct, but as we don't know how `ELEMENTS.bin` is created in first place we cannot tell...

Comment: @Jabberwocky to have the binary with the right length of element and the right order of byte in the _int_ they needed to make the file by a program on the same platforme and compiler, more probably the file is ascii

Comment: @Jabberwocky anyway there are other problems and for them this is sure ^^